# Not showing borders of table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written the following code (ES6) to show a bunch of things in a JSON file within a table:

```
var tablesGlobal2 = 
[
  {"titleRow":[{"string":"Country","alignment":-1},{"string":"Hemisphere","alignment":2}],
  "contentMatrix":[[{"string":"USA","alignment":-1},{"string":"North","alignment":2}],[{"string":"Brazil","alignment":0},{"string":"South","alignment":0}]]},
  {"titleRow":[{"string":"Season","alignment":0},{"string":"Month","alignment":0}],
  "contentMatrix":[[{"string":"Spring","alignment":-1},{"string":"March","alignment":-1}],[{"string":"Spring","alignment":1},{"string":"April","alignment":-1}],[{"string":"Spring","alignment":0},{"string":"May","alignment":2}],[{"string":"Summer","alignment":2},{"string":"June","alignment":2}],[{"string":"Summer","alignment":0},{"string":"July","alignment":0}],[{"string":"Summer","alignment":1},{"string":"August","alignment":2}],[{"string":"Fall","alignment":0},{"string":"September","alignment":0}],[{"string":"Fall","alignment":-1},{"string":"October","alignment":-1}],[{"string":"Fall","alignment":1},{"string":"November","alignment":0}],[{"string":"Winter","alignment":-1},{"string":"December","alignment":2}],[{"string":"Winter","alignment":-1},{"string":"January","alignment":0}],[{"string":"Winter","alignment":2},{"string":"February","alignment":-1}]]}
];

class SampleApplication extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { tables: tablesGlobal2 };
  }
  ShowRowsOfATable(row) { 
    var rows = [];
    row.forEach(function(cell) {
      rows.push(<td> {JSON.stringify(cell.string)} </td> );
    }); 
    return ( {rows} );
  }
  ShowATable(table) { 
    var rows = [];
    var self = this;
    table.contentMatrix.forEach(function(row) {
      var goo = <tr> {self.ShowRowsOfATable(row)} </tr>;
      rows.push(goo);
    }); 
    return (<table> {rows} </table>);  
  } 

  ShowTables(tables) {
    var self = this;
    var rows = [];
    tables.forEach(function(table) {
      rows.push( self.ShowATable(table) );
    });  

    var tableRows = <div>{rows}</div>;
    return (
      <div>  
        {tableRows} 
      </div> 
      ); 
  }
  render() {
    var ts = this.ShowTables(this.state.tables);
    return ( <div> {ts} </div> );
  }
}

React.render(<SampleApplication />, document.body);
```

Here is a sample output: https://jsfiddle.net/danyaljj/0rb0uo8a/ 
[image]

I want to add specifications to the table. For example when I change `<table>` to `<table border="10">` the output still does not change. Similarly, when I change `<td>` to `<td bgcolor="#FF0000">`.

Any idea where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I guess it doesn't work because the `border` attribute is deprecated. Use CSS instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the comment. the thing is I need to assign the background colors programmatically (based on `alignment` values of each cell value; see my JSON file). For example `<td>` should be set to `<td bgcolor="#FF0000">` when `alignment` is one.  I suppose if I set the styling parameters inside CSS, it will be global. Right?

Comment: *"I suppose if I set the styling parameters inside CSS, it will be global."* You can give each element their own style if you want to. Or use classes so multiple elements can share the same style. You can make the rules as specific as you want. `bgcolor` is also deprecated. Maybe have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS to learn more about CSS?

Comment: Apart from Felix's suggestion, you can also use inline styles. React will treat it differently from normal HTML. check https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html for more details.

Comment: @LotAbout Good point. Tnx. Here is what I tried and it worked: https://jsfiddle.net/danyaljj/ud5p4yo0/ But is there anyway to make it a little more flexible; like we assign color based on results of a random integer generator?

Comment: @Daniel Of course see this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lotabout/xzn2bf6s/) for example. I actually don't know whether you want to know how to generate random color or how to apply them. This example should explain.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all Table Attributes here Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).
As said Felix Kling "border" is deprecated ;(

But You can use "borderWidth" and "borderStyle"

```
<table style={{"borderWidth":"1px", 'borderColor':"#aaaaaa", 'borderStyle':'solid'}}></table>
```